# $(document).ready is loading the content after DOM creation, Need content in DOM

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am using coffeeScript which is loading the content after DOM creation. Though, the content is not present in page source, Yet it appears when viewed on firebug.

I want the content to appear on view source also.

What is the alternate for $(document).ready in coffeeScript to get the content in DOM?

Comment: View Source is the HTML as retrieved from the server WITHOUT any JavaScript running. No amount of coffeescript is going to help you here, it is the default browser behaviour. Why does it matter? Want to see the final markup, then press F12 and view it in the developer tools.

Comment: Show your code ! There is no such thing as **'alternate in coffeescript to jQuery`**. Coffescript is a programming language while jQuery is a library.

Comment: alternative would be to not use js to render everything

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest of terms, when a user visits a website an HTML file is downloaded by your browser. This HTML file is static, i.e. it does not mutate or change once it is downloaded. It is the instructions your browser needs so it can understand how to display the HTML as a page. This is what you see when you view the source.

But while this HTML file is being downloaded other instructions contained (or referenced) in the HTML begin to execute, such as JavaScript. The JavaScript can change the DOM but it **doesn't change the original source**. This is why you see something different when viewing it in firebug and viewing the source.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee-script is a language, not a liberary. So the coffee-script equivelant of

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

is simply

```
$(document).ready ->
```

or simpler using the `$(function(){ ...` shorthand, you can do this in coffee-script like this:

```
$ ->
```

Literally thats it. To do `$(document).ready` in coffee-script you still need to include jQuery. Coffee-script and jQuery play nice together :)

---

In re-reading your question, if the content you are looking to get is NOT there in view source, but being added later by another script you do not control, then `$ ->` is not going to be enough to solve your problem. You are going to need to do the DOM selection AFTER it shows up, which means either setting a timer, or using a callback.